# How to handle App and Database on multi-country?

Tags: php, mysql, web, architecture, devops

I wonder how to handle multi-tenancy when you want to launch on multiple country.

Website like Adzuna or Jobtome, do they use one database/app/repo per country or only one for all? (
I think it's easier to maintain if you go for only one big app but does this make sense?

I have a similar case and I don't know what direction to choose...

Comment: Well, both would work. In my case, there are legal implications for `where the data is at rest` , ie Canadian patient's data must be at rest on canuck turf, US->US, etc. So I have multiple DB's AND also multiple stacks to minimize 'data in-flight' intercept possibilities : DB is colocated with stack servers for the country. You chose what is best for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And what about your repo? Do you have one repo for one country

Comment: no. I have one (self provisioned, operated) git repo. My containers start scripts pull from git. My configs are site specific, the generic form is in git. When I create a container for a stack, I hand-craft (for now) the site specific config form the generic that was pulled. Not optimal, but works ok for the moment. I will tend to look for a 'zeroOps' solution shortly and remove error prone hand-crafting.